# Объединение с суммированием стоимости элементов с одинаковой ценой

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции

Есть класс с полями стоимости и количества:

```
class Order {
    private int prise;
    private int volume;

    Order(int prise, int volume) {
        this.prise = prise;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    // и геттеры...
}
```

И коллекция, которая содержит эти элементы: `List<Order> orders = new LinkedList<>();`

В коллекции часто встречаются элементы, у которых одинаковый `prise`. Мне нужно написать такой алгоритм работы с коллекцией, который бы объединил все экземпляры `Order` c одинаковым `prise`, а их `volume` бы при этом сложил.
То есть по результатам работы программы объектов `Order` с одинаковыми `prise` остаться не должно, а поле `volume` должно содержать значение, равное сумме всех `volume`, которые были у удаленных дубликатов.

Но существенным моментом является то, что в коллекции находится несколько тысяч элементов, и скорость в контексте моей задачи имеет большое значение.

Кстати, нужно ли использовать здесь `LinkedList` для хранения данных - тоже вопрос.

Comment: По поводу используемых английских слов: _цена_ пишется как _price_, а для _количество_ гораздо больше подходят _quantity_ и _amount_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с использованием Java 8 Stream API "на максимум":

```
List<Order> groupedOrders = orders.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getPrise, Collectors.summingInt(Order::getVolume)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new Order(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Предполагается, что setter-ов в `Order` нет, поэтому создаётся новый список из новых `Order`.

Тестировал на `ArrayList` из миллиона объектов `Order`:

```
List<Order> orders = IntStream.range(0, 1000 * 1000)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Order(i % 100, i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Время выполнения было в районе 40-45мс. Так что беспокоиться о быстродействии для нескольких тысяч элементов, думаю, не стоит.

---

Со сравнением `ArrayList` с `LinkedList` можно ознакомиться в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist). Как говорится в принятом ответе в этом вопросе: "если не уверены - начните с `ArrayList`".
И в любом случае вряд ли вы заметите хоть какую-то разницу между ними на всего нескольких тысячах элементов.

Comment: Крутой вариант, а скажите пожалуйста если сеттеры есть это будет работать быстрее?

Comment: @Павел конкретно этот код "заточен" под создание нового списка с новыми `Order`. Для переиспользования существующего списка и существующих `Order` придётся весь код переделывать. Если смотреть не на код, а на саму идею переиспользования (за счет существования setter-ов), то незначительного ускорения, думаю, добиться можно. Но, опять-таки повторюсь, различие будет ощущаться только под действительно солидной нагрузкой.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что под "солидной нагрузкой" нужно понимать от 1млн объектов?

Comment: @Павел да, чтобы длина списка исчислялась хотя бы сотнями тысяч элементов. Либо чтобы этот код вызывался сотни раз в секунду. В общем, главное - это сколько времени уходит на выполнение конкретного кода на конкретном компьютере. Согласитесь: если в обоих случаях на выполнение кода уходит меньше одной миллисекунды, то за оптимизацию этого кода заморачиваться не стоит.

Comment: Ух я облажался прайс то у меня в float, не подскажите что нужно изменить что-бы код работал а то я в лямбдах полный ноль((( или лучше другой вопрос создать?

Comment: @Павел а в чём разница в данном случае? Код вполне себе отработает и с `float prise`.

Comment: А я понял проблема в том что у меня еще куча других полей которые тоже просятся в конструктор они на процесс сортировки не влияют их тоже надо както вытащить. new Order(...) Скажите а что возвращают методы e.getKey() и e.getValue() в месте .map(e -> new Order(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))

Comment: @Павел `e.getKey()` возвращает цену, `e.getValue()` - суммарное количество для данной цены. Во второй строке идёт группировка по цене, а результаты попадают в `Map`, из которой в четвёртой строке эти результаты достаются парами "ключ-значение".

Comment: а как поступить с остальными полями? если я использую map то у меня только ключ значение и все а у меня там еще много других полей данные из которых тоже надо сохранить, но я по наивности подумал что если они на процесс слияния не влияют на прямую то можно их и не указывать в вопросе. Или этот вариант подходит если полей у класса Order только два?

Comment: @Павел да, этот код работает только с двумя значениями: одно - по которому группируем, второе - результат агрегирующей функции. По аналогии с `SELECT prise, SUM(volume) FROM Orders GROUP BY prise`.

Answer (score 6):

Идеальный вариант, если предусмотрен set-метод для volume:

```
static Collection<Order> mergeOrdersVolumeSet(Collection<Order> orders){
    //Мапа на основе которой будем объединять. Ключ - price
    final Map<Integer,Order> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
    //Проходим по старым ордерам
    orders.forEach(order -> {
        //Пытаемся по прайсу ордера найти уже существующий
        final Order o = orderMap.get(order.getPrice());
        if (o==null){//Если не нашли - добавляем
            orderMap.put(order.getPrice(),order);
        }else {//Иначе, в уже существующем меняем volume
            o.setVolume(o.getVolume()+order.getVolume());
        }
    });

    return orderMap.values();
}
```

Остальные варианты имеют смысл, если у вас не предусмотрен сеттер для volume.

Можно обойтись без мапы, но не уверен, что так выйдет быстрее:

```
static Collection<Order> mergeOrders(Collection<Order> orders){

    final Collection<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
    //Пока старая коллекция не пуста
    while (!orders.isEmpty()){

        //Использую итератор, т.к. буду удалять из изначальной коллекции.
        final Iterator<Order> oldOrdersIterator = orders.iterator();
        //Получаем первый Ордер
        final Order firstOrder = oldOrdersIterator.next();
        //Одтельно получаем значение кол-ва
        int volume = firstOrder.getVolume();
        //Сразу удаляем его из коллекции
        oldOrdersIterator.remove();
        //Проходим по остальным значениям старой коллекции, если они еще есть
        while (oldOrdersIterator.hasNext()){
            //Получаем текущее
            final Order oldOrder = oldOrdersIterator.next();
            //Если прайс совпадает с первым ордером
            if (firstOrder.getPrice()==oldOrder.getPrice()){
                oldOrdersIterator.remove();//Удаляем его из коллекции
                volume+=oldOrder.getVolume();//Обновляем актуальное значение кол-ва
            }
        }
        //Если значение кол-ва отличается от начального
        if (volume!=firstOrder.getVolume()){
            //Создаем новый ордер на основе старого прайса и нового кол-ва
            result.add(new Order(firstOrder.getPrice(),volume));
        }else {
            //Иначе добавляем неизменившийся
            result.add(firstOrder);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вариант с мапой:

```
static Collection<Order> mergeOrdersMap(Collection<Order> orders){
    //Можно вместо коллекции ордеров использовать Integer значение, равное сумме volumes, но тут не ясно что быстрее.
    // Т.к. в такой ситуации придется заново инициализировать каждый ордер
    Map<Integer,Collection<Order>> mergeMap = new HashMap<>();
    //Проходим по всем старым ордерам
    orders.forEach(order -> {
        //Пытаемся получить коллекцию ордеров с текущим значением прайса
        Collection<Order> keyOrders = mergeMap.get(order.getPrice());
        if (keyOrders==null){//Если не получили
            //то кидаем в мапу новый прайс, и с ним ассоциируем новый лист, в котором пока один ордер
            mergeMap.put(order.getPrice(),new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(order)));
        }else{
            //Иначе добавляем новый ордер
            keyOrders.add(order);
        }
    });
    //Создаем результирующую коллекцию. Сразу задаем размер как у получившейся мапы.
    //Т.к. кол-во прайсов и есть кол-во ордеров после объединения
    final Collection<Order> result = new ArrayList<>(mergeMap.size());
    //Проходим по мапе
    mergeMap.forEach((integer, orders1) -> {
        //Если размер списка == 1, то значит похожих ордеров не было, и можно добавить прямо этот
        if (orders1.size()==1){
            result.add(orders1.stream().findFirst().get());
        }else {
            //Иначе проходим по коллекции, считаем суммарный volume 
            int vol = 0;
            for (Order o: orders1){
                vol+=o.getVolume();
            }
            //И добавляем новый объект
            result.add(new Order(integer,vol));
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Проверка (Результат везде одинаковый):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    orders.add(new Order(1,1));
    orders.add(new Order(2,2));
    orders.add(new Order(3,3));
    orders.add(new Order(4,4));
    orders.add(new Order(1,2));
    orders.add(new Order(2,5));

    orders = mergeOrders(orders);
    orders.forEach(order -> System.out.println("Order -> price: "+order.getPrice()+"; volume: "+order.getVolume()));
}
```

Результат:

> Order -> price: 1; volume: 3
>
> Order -> price: 2; volume: 7
>
> Order -> price: 3; volume: 3
>
> Order -> price: 4; volume: 4

Answer (score 5):

Берете `HashMap<Integer,Order>`, и в него добавляете по одному (`price` -- ключ), перед добавлением проверяете, если уже был добавлен елемент с таким ключем, изменяете его `volume`.